# Securing private network during port forwarding?

Tags: shell, centos, firewall

If I open port to a single server on a private network, will that put every computer in my network at security risk? For example, if I have a company desktop and allow ssh into that desktop from a specific IP. Then will that specific IP be able to snoop around to sniff out data on my personal laptop and phones? If so, how would I secure the personal network?

Comment: If they can ssh in, they can do nearly everything the local user can do.  So, yes, they can sniff around.  But there is a solution: place the company desktop in a DMZ or an otherwise isolated part of the local network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to @John1024

Steps:

1. Setup DMZ with HPC and port forwarded SSH calls to it (using main router). With added whitelisting of particular IPs. Essentially they are public.
2. Set up a secondary router to create a private network for my personal devices.